# xml to pdf converter (bar chart)

Tags: xml, pdf

HI all,

I want to read an xml file and covert into psd file and display the bar chart generated on pdf based on the data provided in xml.

which api can be used for this purpose.

please help.

Comment: Do you need this for a commercial project or just for private use?

Answer (score 0):

There is several approaches to do so. 
1. For writing pdfs you can use ITextSharp free library or commercial pdflib. But I strongly doubt that pdf has notion of charts. So, you probably will need to generate charts as images and only then insert them into pdf. 
2. Generate charts in Excel. The API of Excel is well known. Then you could convert excel to pdf by Nitro  Pdf. Unfortunatly, Nitro Pdf is commercial and has no API. But conversion works quite well and can be done in couple of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Altova's StyleVision](http://www.altova.com/stylevision.html). It's not free or cheap, but it will do exactly what you're asking for: parsing XML data, converting it to a chart and outputting the data in a .PDF file.